# PHP. Read some characters in some strings of a file to write in database

Tags: php, arrays, database, file

I have a file like this:

```
FG  09097612 DN 6575 HL    879797
BHC 09097613 DN 6576 HL    879798
FG  09097614 DN 6577 IOPPP 879799
FG  09097614 DN 6577 IOPPP 879800
```

with its logic that never changes line by line, it is always the same logic.

I would create an array taking the first 2 characters as a variable "nation", then the first 8 characters as a var "prize", then 2 other characters as "player" and so on and create a record in the database for each line.

I am using this code (THE CODE IN TEH EDIT ABOVE IS CHANGED), but not being a csv with delimitation with comma or tab I don't know how to do.

```
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", 1);
$current_row = 1;
$handle = fopen("upload/import.txt", "r");
while ( ($csv_data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, "\t") ) !== FALSE )
{
    $number_of_fields = count($csv_data);
    if ($current_row == 1) {

    }
    else {
      }

fclose($handle);

}
```

I want to put theese var in a record of database, each var in each column.

**What do you recommend?**

Obviously I can not change the original txt file.

**HOW TO SAVE IN DATABASE?**

If I use this code (from one answer above):

```
$lines = file("upload/import.txt");
foreach($lines as $lineNum => $line ) {
    $nation = trim(substr($line, 0, 4)); // get first four characters as nation and remove spaces
    $prize = trim(substr($line, 4, 8)); // get 5th-12th characters as prize and remove spaces
    $player = trim(substr($line, 12, 2)); // get 13th-14th characters as player and remove spaces
```

I use this code:

```
$dbhandle = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};
Server=$myServer;Database=$myDB;", $myUser, $myPass)
or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");

$query = "INSERT INTO TEST (nation) VALUES ('".$nation."')";
echo "<br>Inserted: ".$nation."<br>";
$result = odbc_exec($dbhandle, $query);
```

But it seems to me that this code is too heavy to be done in a foreach? Is not it?

Comment: are you getting data from text file or from CSV? What you are tring to do? Want to make CSV or Write data into database?

Comment: Dear jogesh_pi, I wrote I need to put these vars in a record of a database. Now i have edited question better.

Comment: you can split with whitespace maybe :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.In this situation, delimiter changes because of the formatting so I suggest you treat it as a string but not a csv.

```
FG  09097612 DN 6575 HL    879797
BHC 09097613 DN 6576 HL    879798
FG  09097614 DN 6577 IOPPP 879799
FG  09097614 DN 6577 IOPPP 879800

$lines = file("upload/import.txt");
foreach($lines as $lineNum => $line ) {
    $nation = trim(substr($line, 0, 4)); // get first four characters as nation and remove spaces
    $prize = trim(substr($line, 4, 8)); // get 5th-12th characters as prize and remove spaces
    $player = trim(substr($line, 12, 2)); // get 13th-14th characters as player and remove spaces
}
```

2.Or if you insist on using csv parser, you should  make consecutive spaces into one before you actually use `fgetscsv`:

```
$tempfile = "tmp/temp".microtime()."csv"; // a temp folder where you have write authority, `microtime()` here is used to generate a unique filename.
$content = file_get_contents("upload/import.txt");
while(strpos($content,"  ") !== false) {
    // while consecutive spaces exist
    $content = str_replace("  ", " ", $content);
}
file_put_contents($tempfile, $content);
```

Then you can treat it as a normal csv file with space delimiter like this:

```
$handle = fopen($tempfile, "r");
$current_row = 1;
while ( ($csv_data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, " ") ) !== FALSE )
{
    $number_of_fields = count($csv_data);
    // ...
}
fclose($handle);
```

After you finish this , delete the temp file like this:

```
unlink($tempfile);
```

And it is better to do the insert only once than create and run the insert query in a `foreach` loop, so instead of adding

```
$query = "INSERT INTO TEST (nation) VALUES ('".$nation."')";
$result = odbc_exec($dbhandle, $query);
```

in each loop, which produces

```
INSERT INTO TEST (nation) VALUES ('FG');
INSERT INTO TEST (nation) VALUES ('BHC');
INSERT INTO TEST (nation) VALUES ('FG');
INSERT INTO TEST (nation) VALUES ('FG');
...
```

, it is more reasonable to create the query like this

```
$lines = file("upload/import.txt");
$dbhandle = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};
Server=$myServer;Database=$myDB;", $myUser, $myPass)
or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
$query = "INSERT INTO TEST (nation) VALUES \n";
$row = array(); // query for each line
foreach($lines as $lineNum => $line ) {
    $nation = trim(substr($line, 0, 4)); // get first four characters as nation and remove spaces
    $prize = trim(substr($line, 4, 8)); // get 5th-12th characters as prize and remove spaces
    $player = trim(substr($line, 12, 2)); // get 13th-14th characters as player and remove spaces
    $row []= "(".$nation.")";
}
$query .= implode(",\n",$row).";";
$result = odbc_exec($dbhandle, $query);
```

If you echo `$query`, you should get something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TEST (nation) VALUES 
('FG'),
('BHC'),
('FG'),
('FG');
```

which is much more light to run insert query every line.

PS: Please be careful that mysql has a limited query length. If the query is longer than max length, you will get an error , something like 'Mysql has gone away...'. I haven't much experience in using ms-sql server but there should be a same limit.

In this situation, you should split the query in a proper way. For example, run and clear the query every 10000 lines like this:

```
$lines = file("upload/import.txt");
$dbhandle = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};
Server=$myServer;Database=$myDB;", $myUser, $myPass) or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
$query = "INSERT INTO TEST (nation) VALUES \n";
$row = array(); // query for each line
foreach($lines as $lineNum => $line ) {
    $nation = trim(substr($line, 0, 4)); // get first four characters as nation and remove spaces
    $prize = trim(substr($line, 4, 8)); // get 5th-12th characters as prize and remove spaces
    $player = trim(substr($line, 12, 2)); // get 13th-14th characters as player and remove spaces
    $row []= "('".$nation."')";

    if($lineNum % 10000 == 9999){
        // run and reproduce the query every 10000 lines
        $query .= implode(",\n",$row).";";
        // put 'echo $query;' here would help you understand the design
        $result = odbc_exec($dbhandle, $query);
        // It is better to check the result here if it success
        // The query has been run so it should be initialized again, so is $row.
        $query = "INSERT INTO TEST (nation) VALUES \n";
        $row = array(); // query for each line
    }
}
$query .= implode(",\n",$row).";";
$result = odbc_exec($dbhandle, $query);
```

Answer to 'I need now to check if in the file there are lines with the same nation, in this example "FG" and sum the $prize of each "FG" and save only the total in prize and not all the lines of FG? '

Of course you can do that, since I don't know your table or how you would like to save your other data so I will just provide a sample with only `nation` and `price`:

```
$lines = file("upload/import.txt");
$dbhandle = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};
Server=$myServer;Database=$myDB;", $myUser, $myPass)
or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
$query = "INSERT INTO TEST (nation, prize) VALUES \n";
$row = array(); // data for each line
foreach($lines as $lineNum => $line ) {
    $nation = trim(substr($line, 0, 4)); // get first four characters as nation and remove spaces
    $prize = trim(substr($line, 4, 8)); // get 5th-12th characters as prize and remove spaces
    $row[$nation] = !empty($row[$nation])? $row[$nation] + (int)$prize : 0 ; // make sure prize is an interger in your file
}
// Since there are not so much nations in the world, I don't think it is necessary to worry about the max query length
$query_row = array(); // query for each line
foreach($row as $nation => $sum_prize){
    $query_row []= "('".$nation."','".$sum_prize."')";
}
$query .= implode(",\n",$query_row).";";
$result = odbc_exec($dbhandle, $query);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code works very well, but there is a but and I edited my question. HOW TO SAVE IN DATABASE? I use this code: `$query = "INSERT INTO TEST (nation) VALUES ('".$nation."')"; echo "<br>Inserted: ".$nation."<br>"; $result = odbc_exec($dbhandle, $query);` But it seems to me that this code is too heavy to be done in a foreach? Is not it?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is heavy to run the query in a foreach loop and there is a better way. I 've updated my answer and please check the sql part. Hope this would help.

Comment: You are amazing! Everything works and I'm so glad. But there is one problem: when values in my query contains only numbers everything works, when there is at least one letter like "b" I have this error: `Warning: odbc_exec():`. My table in database (MSSQL 2012) is a simple: nation-nchar(10), prize-nchar(10), player- nchar(10). For nation and player which are numbers everything works and the query write in database. When I put in query the player (there are names of the player in this field like "tom") I have the error. Why? My query: `$row []="(".$nation.",".$prize.",".$player.")";`

Comment: You forgot to put single quote in your query and I forgot too :), Change it to `$row []="('".$nation."','".$prize."','".$player."')";` might work.

Comment: Ok, kyo. Everything works with quote. What I don'ut understand yet is how to "split" the lines in 999 for the query lenght limit. What you do with `if($lineNum % 10000 == 9999){` ? I have to repeat the query statement before and after the `else`?

Comment: It is hard to explain it using just comment so I've updated my last sample. Please check it and if you put `echo $query` where I commented and change to a smaller number (say `$lineNum % 10 == 9`) , it will help you understand better.

Comment: Kyo, you are amazing. We are just finishing... One more thing: I must repeat two time the query and the row declaration? One time isn't better?

Comment: Making the declaration again is to clear the current value of `$query` and `$row`. If we don't clear them, we will insert the first 10000 rows again when we make the second `$query`. There are also other ways to approach this with only one declaration but as far as I'm concerned, this is better because other ways will be complicated and hard to maintain.

Comment: Ok, kyo. I trust you. But how about you write nevertheless an example of how it could be? Because sometimes I need to declare tables to use (INSERT INTO TEST (table1, table2, table3)) and change every time is not nice if I have 10 queries * 2 = 20 query to modify!

Comment: The last thing, kyo, I swear: I need now to check if in the file there are lines with the same nation, in this example "FG" and sum the $prize of each "FG" and save only the total in prize and not all the lines of FG?

Comment: Updated my answer to the last question. About declaration, what I had in mind is to create a query anyway, no matter how long it gets. And when you finish creating the query, create a function, something like `function splitQuery($query, $length)` to split the query into pieces. The purpose of `splitQuery($query, $length)` is to get the query and to split it into queries by length. On top of my head, this function could be about 100 lines and not easy to maintain. Maybe there is another simpler way but I'm out.

Comment: Ok. Kyo. Thanks. It works. You created a second query before creating the final query. Even I had thought of such a thing. I am pleased with myself. One thing: if I want to avoid the inclusion of a line if the nation was "FG"? In practice it would be nice if there was a chance to have a kind of "skip" in the "foreach" to check line by line each variable and then proceed according to different criteria. One of these, for example, is "to skip" if, for example, the nation is "FG". How to "skip"? I need to skip in "foreach", i'm right?

Comment: You can use `if($nation == 'FG'){continue;}` to skip to next loop or `if($nation == 'FG'){break;}` to terminate the loop and skip to the code after the loop.

Comment: Kyo great, thanks a lot. I, waiting for a reply, already used your code without the braces that I think just to "continue" are not necessary. In fact everything works. There is only one last problem (and then I swear I'll stop and add the star you deserved): when the script runs and of course "skip" all because according to my criteria, there is nothing to add in query I get the error `Warning: odbc_exec ():` because the query hasn't  "VALUES". How do I write an error based on the "skip" that I do?

Comment: I don't know your code but in my last code, you can check if `$query_row` is empty before you use it. `if(!empty($query_row)){$query .= implode(",\n",$query_row).";"; $result = odbc_exec($dbhandle, $query);  }`

Comment: kyo, I need 1 more thing, plz. I have another table with the players list for each nation. For each player I have additional information, eg how many times has marked the record or the score in other games. How can I read, for every nation, what did every player in the second table and use that data for other insert? I have this logical idea: make a small array with all the players in the second table with "Select * from table where Nation 2nd = $ nation", but I need then go player by player this new array by analyzing the data and working and saving them in a third table.

Comment: That is one way. If the logic is not complicated, you can also finish it in sql using `INSERT INTO table3 (col1,col2,...) SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM table2 GROUP BY col3`, which is faster.

Comment: No, kyo. I have not explained well.

I need to check if an array like this: (["1"] => "30/11/2001 00:00:00" ["302"] => '2001-12-01 00:00:00 "[" 522 "] =>" 01/12/2012 00:00:00 "[" 1 "] =>" 30/11/2001 00:00:00 "etc.) already exists the value pair that I am going to add. If already exists, I want to do some things, otherwise I want to do other things.

How do I find in the array (like the array I wrote) if already exists one or more pairs of values "[" key "] => [" value "] ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$handle = fopen("upload/import.txt", "r");
$current_row = 1;
while(!feof($handle)){
$str=fgets($handle);//read one line of the file
$str=str_replace("  "," ",$str);//reduce all consecutive spaces to single space
$arr=explode(" ",$str);
if ($current_row == 1) {

}
else {
 }
}
fclose($handle);
```

Now the array $arr will contain the strings {"FG","09097612,"DN","6575","HL","879797"} (after reading the first line). You can use this array to access the values and insert them in DB.

EDIT:

I understand that you want to have an array called "nation" which will contain values {"FG","BHC","FG","FG"}, and the same for prize and other variables. Try this code:

```
$nation=array();
$prize=array();
$player=array();
$handle = fopen("upload/import.txt", "r");
$current_row = 1;
while(!feof($handle)){
$str=fgets($handle);//read one line of the file
$str=str_replace("  "," ",$str);//reduce all consecutive spaces to single space
$arr=explode(" ",$str);
//now insert values in respective arrays
array_push($nation,$arr[0]);
array_push($prize,$arr[1]);
array_push($player,$arr[2]);
//and so on
if ($current_row == 1) {

}
else {
 }
}
fclose($handle);
```

Now you can use the arrays $nation, $prize and $player. You can create arrays for the other values in the same manner.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Dear westlife, thanks. But I need to create the first var with the first "n" characters in line, the second var with the second "n" characters in the same line and so on... With each array (with these vars) I need to put into record of my database. How to?